# List windows and detect new windows

Tags: c#, wpf, hwnd

I'd like to get a list of all the windows every time a new window is created.
For now, I'm using a timer which gets an enumeration of all the windows.

But I'd like to avoid using a timer, and subscribe to any kind of event that is triggered when a window (or a process) is created...

How could I do this?

Comment: All which windows? The ones in your process? Some other process? All processes?

Comment: All windows in all processes

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor all Window creating processes using [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx) with a [CBTProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644977(v=VS.85).aspx)