# Create an Event for when this,toplevel value changes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, toplevel

I want to be able to have my application to always be on top. so when I open a new program and that becomes on top even though I have this.TopLevel value set to true, the application will see it is not on top no more and then go back on top.
I know I can do this with a timer, but I am hoping their is a better way.

Comment: But should you be determining what window appears to the user in their multitasking environment?

Comment: this is a overlay application that has a check box to activate this feature.

Comment: What if someone else wrote the same program?

Comment: Just in case you are using WPF, it has a built-in feature to keep the application on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a method located in `user32.dll`.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

You are going to need these variables:

```
private static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
private const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
private const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
private const UInt32 TOPMOST_FLAGS = SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE;
```

Import the method from the DLL...

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")] 
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
```

Then in your code, use this to set the window position to the topmost window.

```
SetWindowPos(this.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);
```

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you catch the event for new windows and see if you are on top after the new window opens:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40698254/2557128